# PDF Low-Level: Blur Filter

Tags: pdf, blur

Is it possible to apply a blur filter over a PDF page to blur all content on the page? If so, how is this done from the page object?

I'm asking about how to do it in low-level PDF format, not how to do it using any libraries.

Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand why this question was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add semi-transparent "overlay" atop of existing page contents.

"Overlay" might be a picture, XForm object, optional content group and maybe something else.

Or you could setup one of the pre-defined blend modes and fill entire page with a color. It might not give you exactly blur effect but might distort contents in a similar way.

Effect of pre-defined blend modes is illustrated in these PDF files:

- [Blend modes (solid brushes)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yghN6WYluqrSKlkhc4QGLrcbHW3wLCEm/view?usp=sharing)
- [Blend modes (images)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WRuF9MT3cmM5jA8o3EJQfnhI52Ik6NDl/view?usp=sharing)